# Cannot Run Ruby on Rails application from NetBeans IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans6.8

I am trying to Run (F6) a Rails application from NetBeans 6.8 and when i do so I get the following output in the lower left hand status bar of the IDE:

```
Could not connect to the web server - could not show http://localhost:3000
```

I don't believe that the WEbrick server is even starting, but i can start WEBrick and the same  application I'm working with in NetBeans from the command line.

I am running Ruby 1.9.1, Rails 2.3.5, WEBrick 1.3.1 and NetBeans 6.8 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, found the answer. Was a bug in NetBeans but there is a workaround: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=158794