# Problem with starting RubyOnRails app in NetBeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, encoding, webserver

Good time for everyone!

Using NetBeans 7.0 for RubyOnRails app I found that clear project (without any changes by mine) doesn't start and I'seeing mesage ib sttaus bar "Impossible to connect to web-server - cannot to show localhost:3000" (tranlsation is mine, becouse of I use russified version on IDE). In console I see the error, that are. possible, connected with the starting problem -

**C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1090:in `block in loaded_path?': incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-1251 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)**

Please, help me with this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978500/cannot-run-ruby-on-rails-application-from-netbeans-ide), so it could be an error from netbeans side, you may get answer from netbeans support forum.

Have a look at [linimiatations in running ror on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164896/limitations-in-running-ruby-rails-on-windows)